# Meteor iron-router on server-side route - why so slow?

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

11,222 requests/sec with raw Node...

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end('done');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

=

> **gobench -c 100 -t 5 -u http://localhost:1337**

```
Requests:                            56112 hits
Successful requests:                 56112 hits
Network failed:                          0 hits
Bad requests failed (!2xx):              0 hits
Successfull requests rate:           11222 hits/sec
Read throughput:                   1369156 bytes/sec
Write throughput:                  1349088 bytes/sec
Test time:                               5 sec
```

But with an Iron-Router server-side route in Meteor returning the same thing...

```
Router.route('/test', function() {
    this.response.end('done');
}, {
    where: 'server'
});
```

=

> **gobench -c 100 -t 5 -u http://localhost:3000/test**

```
Requests:                             6544 hits
Successful requests:                  6544 hits
Network failed:                          0 hits
Bad requests failed (!2xx):              0 hits
Successfull requests rate:            1308 hits/sec
Read throughput:                    189776 bytes/sec
Write throughput:                   164771 bytes/sec
Test time:                               5 sec
```

Is the bottleneck Meteor or Iron-Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottleneck is a combination of a few things.

When you use a vanilla `http` server you're missing out the middlewares used by Meteor and Iron Router (bodyparser & route matching) & route matching kit (meteor side). Also keep in mind Iron Router uses regexp to match routes.

The other thing is in `meteor run` mode (that is not the bundled app from `meteor build`) has an additional proxy server ontop of the app itself.

There are also a couple of other middlwares to check where to route the file from, (i.e whether its a static asset or not) (including for which architecture (cordova or client).

Additionally the `index.html` file has to be generated per runtime in Meteor.

A hint of the Middleware used by Meteor come from the `webapp` package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js